# Facebook login - issue after Graph request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been going through docs [Android - Facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/)

for days still the issue that I'm facing is - just after the user logs in for first time and after the graph request and the api call,the `intentToHomeScreen()` method is not called. Note that this happens in rare cases. The progress bar keeps on loading.
Here's my code, sorry for posting such long post:

```
public class SignInActivity extends BaseActivity {

    final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 1;
    @BindView(R.id.sign_fb_splash_linear)
    LinearLayout mSignIn;
    @BindView(R.id.sign_in_logo_img)
    ImageView mLogoImg;
    @BindView(R.id.splash_relative)
    RelativeLayout mRelative;
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private Profile profile;
    private String fbid;
    private String fUserName;
    private String gender;
    private String email;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private SharedPref preferences;
    private Context mContext;

    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar)
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private User userFromResponse;
    private GpsLocation mGpsLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setting the context
        mContext = this;

        preferences = SharedPref.getInstance(mContext);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplication());

        if (BuildConfig.enableCrashlytics) {
            Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mGpsLocation = GpsLocation.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), this);
        mGpsLocation.onStart();

        if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
            intentToHomeScreen();
        }

        Animation animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);
        mSignIn.startAnimation(animShow);
    }

    private void intentToHomeScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private boolean userIsLoggedIn() {
        return preferences.getLongValue(mContext, preferences.KEY_USER_ID) != 0;
    }


    private void initialiseFacebookSdk() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                showProgressBar(true, progressBar);

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                try {
                                    if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null && object != null && response != null) {
                                        profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                        email = object.optString("email");
                                        gender = object.optString("gender");
                                        fbid = profile.getId();
                                        fUserName = profile.getName();
                                        imageUri = profile.getProfilePictureUri(300, 300);
                                        String loginType = "Facebook";

                                        User user = new User();
                                        user.email = email;
                                        user.phoneNumber = "";
                                        user.loginType = loginType;
                                        user.gender = gender;
                                        user.name = fUserName;
                                        user.facebookId = fbid;

                                        // sending to api
                                        IAppAPIInterface apiManagerInterface = ApiManager.getApiManager();

                                        Call<User> call = apiManagerInterface.postFbDetails(user);
                                        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                                                showProgressBar(false, progressBar);
                                                if (response != null && response.body() != null) {
                                                    userFromResponse = response.body();

                                                    if (preferences != null) {
                                                        SharedPref.setBoolean(mContext, preferences.KEY_FIRST_USE_HOME, true);
                                                        SharedPref.setLong(mContext, preferences.KEY_USER_ID, userFromResponse.userRecordId);
                                                        SharedPref.setString(mContext, preferences.KEY_NAME, userFromResponse.name);
                                                        SharedPref.setString(mContext, preferences.KEY_PROF_IMG_URL, String.valueOf(imageUri));
                                                        SharedPref.setString(mContext, preferences.KEY_USER_TOKEN, userFromResponse.token);
                                                    }
                                                    // Sending to home screen
                                                    intentToHomeScreen();
                                                } else if (response != null) {
                                                    AppUtilityMethods.getInstance(SignInActivity.this).showMsgToast(SignInActivity.this, response.message(), mSignIn);
                                                }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                                                showProgressBar(false, progressBar);
                                                if (t.getMessage().equals("timeout")) {
                                                    AppUtilityMethods.getInstance(SignInActivity.this).showMsgToast(SignInActivity.this, getString(R.string.timeout), mSignIn);
                                                } else {
                                                    AppUtilityMethods.getInstance(SignInActivity.this).showMsgToast(SignInActivity.this, t.getMessage(), mSignIn);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                showProgressBar(false, progressBar);
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "On Cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException ex)
            {
                showProgressBar(false, progressBar);
                AppUtilityMethods.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).showMsgToast(getApplicationContext(), "Connetion error!", null);
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "On Error:    " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                }
                return;
            }

            case OpenDialogPermission.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mGpsLocation.isGPSEnable();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGpsLocation.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGpsLocation.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGpsLocation.checkPermissions();
    }

    @OnClick({R.id.sign_fb_splash_linear})
    void onClick() {
        if (Utilities.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            initialiseFacebookSdk();
        } else {
            AppUtilityMethods.getInstance(this).showNetworkNotAvailToast(this, mSignIn);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your logs whenever you got this issue. Sometimes, response can be null. And in rare cases means when?

Comment: Rare cases means specially when the user doesn't have the app installed in Fb and he/she logs in for first time.

Comment: I've followed the docs as mentioned exactly.Still I know something is wrong.